# How to add multiple vertical rectangles to a single chart in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm struggling to figure out how to create multiple rectangles that span entire plots using plotly.

I've done this with matplotlib using axvspan():

```
for month in recession:
plt.axvspan(month, month + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0), color="red", alpha=0.1)
```

I'm assuming this is possible using add_vrect()?

Below is the code along with a sample data set that I want to add the vertical rectangles to with the hope of spanning all of the dates corresponding with the Recession periods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime

# Load data
history = pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv")
history["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(history["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
history.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

# Filter out recession dates
recession = history.loc[history["Regime"] == "Recession"].index

# Plot Dow Jones average against time
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=history.index, y=history["DJI"], mode="lines"))

# Show plot
fig.show()
```

Sample Data

| Date | Regime | DJI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1907-01-01 | Normal | 68.33 |
| 1907-02-01 | Normal | 66.41 |
| 1907-03-01 | Normal | 65.57 |
| 1907-04-01 | Recession | 58.05 |
| 1907-05-01 | Recession | 61.05 |
| 1907-06-01 | Recession | 56.56 |
| 1907-07-01 | Recession | 57.94 |
| 1907-08-01 | Normal | 62.35 |
| 1907-09-01 | Normal | 63.01 |
| 1907-10-01 | Normal | 63.29 |
| 1907-11-01 | Normal | 62.99 |
| 1907-12-01 | Normal | 63.17 |
| 1908-01-01 | Normal | 63.28 |
| 1908-02-01 | Normal | 63.41 |
| 1908-03-01 | Normal | 63.83 |
| 1908-04-01 | Normal | 63.11 |
| 1908-05-01 | Recession | 59.26 |
| 1908-06-01 | Recession | 58.99 |
| 1908-07-01 | Recession | 58.37 |
| 1908-08-01 | Recession | 58.01 |
| 1908-09-01 | Recession | 57.66 |
| 1908-10-01 | Recession | 57.23 |
| 1908-11-01 | Recession | 56.84 |
| 1908-12-01 | Recession | 56.76 |
| 1909-01-01 | Recession | 56.24 |
| 1909-02-01 | Recession | 57.15 |
| 1909-03-01 | Recession | 57.89 |
| 1909-04-01 | Normal | 61.01 |
| 1909-05-01 | Normal | 61.34 |
| 1909-06-01 | Normal | 61.92 |
| 1909-07-01 | Normal | 62.39 |
| 1909-08-01 | Normal | 63.01 |
| 1909-09-01 | Normal | 63.22 |
| 1909-10-01 | Normal | 63.89 |
| 1909-11-01 | Normal | 64.21 |
| 1909-12-01 | Normal | 64.88 |

Comment: Try this:[https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#setting-label-anchors](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#setting-label-anchors)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience using Plotly, but I think the issue is that you're trying to use Plotly to create part of the figure and matplotlib to create the other. Instead, you can do it all in matplotlib.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

# Load data
history = pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv")
history["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(history["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
history.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

# Filter out recession dates
recession = history.loc[history["Regime"] == "Recession"].index

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for month in recession:
    plt.axvspan(month, month + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0), color="grey", alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(history.index, history.DJI, "-.")
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=45)
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("DJI")
ax.set_title("DJI Over Time")
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

The vertical bands are from the start of one month and end of the other overlapping slightly. I leave it to you to figure out how to find the ranges of each recession and plot the gray band from the start to the end.